# How to use the RP3200 Plus Thermal Printer

Tags: c, printing, esp32, uart, thermal-printer

I am using the thermal printer RP3200 Plus by TVS and trying to print the receipt which contains the simple name like "Rohan" or some thing else using the ESP32 controller through the UART protocol.

What i have done is that i have configured the UART and Made the two function from sending the command and for configuring the UART. But i am not getting the expected output.
Below is the short and simple code for this.

```
#define UART_TX_PIN 1  // Replace with your ESP32 TX pin
#define UART_RX_PIN 3  // Replace with your ESP32 RX pin
#define UART_NUM 0

void initialize_uart() {
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 9600,  // Adjust based on your printer's specifications
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE
    };

    uart_param_config(UART_NUM, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM, UART_TX_PIN, UART_RX_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM, 256, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
}

void send_command(const char* command) {
    uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM, command, strlen(command));
}

void print_yash() {
// Reset Printer
    send_command("\x1B\x40");

// Set Bold Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x45\x01");

// Set Underline Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x2D\x01");

// Set Double-Strike Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x47\x01");

// Set Font Size (Double Height and Width)
    send_command("\x1D\x21\x11");

// Center Align
    send_command("\x1B\x61\x01");

// Print Text
    send_command("Yash\n");

// Left Align
    send_command("\x1B\x61\x00");

// Disable Bold Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x45\x00");

// Disable Underline Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x2D\x00");

// Disable Double-Strike Mode
    send_command("\x1B\x47\x00");

// Cut Paper
    send_command("\x1D\x56\x00");
}

void app_main() {
    initialize_uart();
    print_yash();

    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
```